# Add 0 prefix if less than max length

Tags: jquery

I Have a input field for account nos.

```
<input type="text" name="Account no" class="account" />
```

By default 4 digits have to be there minimum or maximum.

If user types, `23` - it have to change `0023` once user focus out of input.
If user types, `3` -  it have to change `0003` once user focus out of input.
If user types, `123` - it have to change `0123` once user focus out of input.

How can I create this behaviour using jQuery?

Comment: `while(variable.length < 4){ variable = '0' + variable; }` quite simple actually

Comment: Combine Kaddath's comment with https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".account").on('blur', function() {
  var str = "" + $(this).val();
  var pad = "0000"
  var ans = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;
  $(this).val(ans);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Account no" class="account" maxlength=4 />
```